# Which is faster: $(".elt", $this) or $this.find(".elt");?

Tags: jquery, performance

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Given the above, which is faster: `$(".elt", $this)` or `$this.find(".elt")`?

I ask because the first seems a bit more concise, but if it converts to `$($this).find(".elt")` [sic], it seems that it could in fact be slower.

Comment: I assume you have a performance problem you are troubleshooting and aren't just wasting time on micro-optimizations?

Comment: @JohnFx There's nothing wrong with simply being curious. Actually, I view that as a virtue.

Comment: @JohnFx has a good point about micro-optimizations. Spend your time wisely on what matters and you will have a lot more time. Wait, why am I commenting on this then. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is much faster to use `$("#elt")` since there is only one element with an `id="elt"` that is a valid element. *(ID's MUST BE UNIQUE)*

Edit: If you were only using that as an example, and the same question applies to using a class instead of an ID, Both ways should be relatively the same due to the way jquery works internally.

`$(".elt", $this)` converts to `$this.find(".elt")` which is identical to `$this.find(".elt")`.

You may find a difference between the two after running several thousand iterations of it at once, but in normal circumstances, you are better off using the one that is easier to read.

Comment: Sorry, but I used "#elt" just as a general example. I changed it from an ID selector to a class to be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: I figured that was the case, so I updated my answer with that answer too.

Comment: Another thing to note, If you are minifying your code, the first way should minify smaller than the second one.

Answer (score 3):

The performance difference between those two is negligible.

`$( 'selector', context )` is transformed into `$( context ).find( 'selector' )` at the very beginning of the jQuery `$()` function. We are talking microseconds here (if not nanoseconds).

(I prefer the shorter form because it's... well, shorter.)